# Regex in Java: How do I know if a specific part of Regex matches or not?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to implement a paper. The author has a pattern:

> u*v+w+

And he said if 'u*' is not empty,"blablabla" else empty another choice. But how could I know if 'u*' is matched or not in the whole part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use captured groups e.g. `(u*)v+w+` as regex and then check `matcher.group(1)` to determine whether `u*` matched or not.